# upload file on s3 using presigned url in laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I'm creating presigned URL with aws-laravel for uploading files to S3 bucket.

When trying to print presignedurl  I'm getting and error SignatureDoesNotMatch with message The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

```
Here is the code
 $s3Client = new S3Client([
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.key'),
                'secret' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.secret'),
            ],
            'region' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.region'),
            'version' => 'latest',
        ]);
        $expiry = "+20 minutes";

       
        $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', [
            'Bucket' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket'),
            'Key' => $path,
        ]);


        $request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, $expiry);
        $presignedUrl = (string)$request->getUri();

       
       //curl to put data on s3 bucket

        //Set up the file to upload
        $file = $videofile;

        // Get the contents of the file
        $fileContents = file_get_contents($file);

        // Set the headers for the PUT request
        $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'MP4',
        'Content-Length' => strlen($fileContents),
        ];

        // Make the PUT request using cURL
        $ch = curl_init($presignedUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fileContents);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
```

here I am creating presigned url to put object on s3

Answer (score 0):

Not able to find whre you added the credentials.

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'your-access-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret-key',
    ],
]);
```